# How to generate list when word is selected?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I generate list with words that is attached to the selected word?

I have a table like this:

Column1

I eat banana

I have beautiful car

Lets say person double click on word banana, thus it is selected.

I need to generate component with other words that is attached to the selected word.

Comment: hey can you provide the code snippet like so far what you have tried...that will help you to learn in an effective way and then we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the [`selectionchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event), figure out if the [new selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) is [in one of your list elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorNode) (using refs or `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` to keep track of them) then [read the selection's text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/toString) and then do your usual React magic to generate the other component.

Comment: or just use an array and use index to keep track of the clicked item.

Comment: I think OP wants to leverage the browser's text selection API. Of course if each clickable word is a component of its own, then none of that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a component that split a string into an array and display parts of the string as a separate html element.
Example:

```
class WordList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick (word) {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(word);
  }

  render () {
    const { word } = this.props;
    const wordsArr = word.split(" ");

    return (
      wordsArr.map((w, i) => (
       <>
          <span onClick={() => this.onClick(w)} key={i}>{w}</span> 
          <span> </span>
       </>
      ))
    )
  }
}

export default WordList;
```

And then you can include component like this:

```
<WordList onClick={(word) => alert(word)} word={'I eat banana'} />
```